# My Cython code parses into C, but doesn't compile. First time trying to use external C code

Tags: compiler-errors, cython

I am trying to compile this code:

[interp3d.pyx](http://pastebin.com/CaHLVJ4p)

along with the library provided here:

[Interpolate3D](http://code.google.com/p/interpolate3d/)

It gets past the cython -> C stage without any errors, but there's a crapton of errors with gcc:

[Compile-time errors---dunno if this helps or not](http://pastebin.com/PTSYByV0)

Excerpt from compile errors:

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -O2 -I/home/jordango/Desktop/epd-7.0-2-rh5-x86/include -fPIC -I/home/jordango/Desktop/epd-7.0-2-rh5-x86/include/python2.7 -c interp3d.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/interp3d.o
interp3d.c:225:31: error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory
interp3d.c:226:31: error: numpy/ufuncobject.h: No such file or directory
```

If someone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here, that would be awesome. It's sort of hard to know what to make look like C and what to make look like Python.

If it helps, I'm using Cython 0.14.1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have installed numpy in your system ...

in your setup.py you have to write :

```
import numpy 
...
Extension(..., include_dirs = [numpy.get_include(), ... ] )
```

Comment: including the "..."s?  I mean, `Extension(include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])` doesn't seem to work, as it is undefined...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's an unsatisfied dependency on `numpy`, judging by the "No such files"
errors.