# Python/Cython: Using SciPy with Cython

Tags: python, c, statistics, scipy, cython

The Cython tutorial shows a nice example of how to use Numpy with Cython. However, I have code that uses the scipy.stats package and when attempting to compile the code, I errors such as:

```
dvi.pyx:7:8: 'scipy.stats.pxd' not found
```

I fear that scipy is not supported with Cython (?). Can someone comment on the use of scipy with Cython or point me in the direction of some resources/tutorials? Thannks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I found code on the Cython Google Group (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/cython-users/using$20scipy/cython-users/CF9GqYN1aPU/WKC-N9c6zpgJ)

That shows the following as imports:

```
import pylab as PL
from scipy import integrate
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.integrate import odeint

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
```

Which gave me confidence I could compile with SciPy. When adding the `cimport cython` statement, I receive the following compilation errors:

```
dvi.c:237:31: error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory
dvi.c:238:31: error: numpy/ufuncobject.h: No such file or directory
```

Which seemed like there was a path or directory issue. In fact I was correct and there is a post on this site ([My Cython code parses into C, but doesn't compile. First time trying to use external C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525161/my-cython-code-parses-into-c-but-doesnt-compile-first-time-trying-to-use-exte))

The solution was to add the following to my setup.py file:

```
import numpy 
...
Extension(..., include_dirs = [numpy.get_include(), ... ] )
```

W00t!

Comment: I added `Extension(include_dirs = [numpy.get_include()])` to setup.py, and nada...says `Extension` is undefined.  Is there more you have to do?

Answer (score 2):

Write

```
import scipy.stats
```

not

```
cimport scipy.stats
```